# jQuery file uploader showing error when restrictions has been added

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload

I wanted a jQuery multi file uploader with process bar. Thats why I went to this [url](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). In this there is one option called [basic](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html). I just downloaded all the files and I used only the basic.html file. With basic.html files code  I can easily upload files. But I want some restriction so that user will only upload some kind of files like png,jpg and gif only. So to use restriction in upload I checked for documentation and I got this [link](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#acceptfiletypes).
So I mixed all the codes like this

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <span>Select files...</span>
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- The global progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
    <div id="files" class="files"></div>
    <br>
</div>

<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === '' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        options: {
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        processQueue: [
            action: 'validate',
            acceptFileTypes: '@',
            disabled: '@disableValidation'
        ]
    },
    processActions: {

        validate: function (data, options) {
            if (options.disabled) {
                return data;
            }
            var dfd = $.Deferred(),
                file = data.files[data.index],
            if (!options.acceptFileTypes.test(file.type)) {
                file.error = 'Invalid file type.';
                dfd.rejectWith(this, [data]);
            } else {
                dfd.resolveWith(this, [data]);
            }
            return dfd.promise();
        }

    }
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

But here I can't upload any files also I can't get restriction in upload. After all this codes in my firefox console tab I got an error like

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
action: 'validate',
```

Can someone kindly tell me why this error is here? How to solve this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Missing a comma there between literal objects, after `processActions`

```
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === '' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        options: {
          acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
          processQueue: [
              action: 'validate',
              acceptFileTypes: '@',
              disabled: '@disableValidation'
          ],
          processActions: {

              validate: function (data, options) {
                  if (options.disabled) {
                      return data;
                  }
                  var dfd = $.Deferred(),
                      file = data.files[data.index],
                  if (!options.acceptFileTypes.test(file.type)) {
                      file.error = 'Invalid file type.';
                      dfd.rejectWith(this, [data]);
                  } else {
                      dfd.resolveWith(this, [data]);
                  }
                  return dfd.promise();
              }

          },
          done: function (e, data) {
              $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                  $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
              });
          },
          progressall: function (e, data) {
              var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
              $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                  'width',
                  progress + '%'
              );
          }
        } // end of options
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```